# How to refer to the 'sections' of an aquarium?

Tags: word-choice

When you visit an aquarium, you see different species of marine life in different 'sections.' They are usually surrounded by glass.

I want to build sentences like this:

> I walked to another '**glass/section**.' In it, I could see a many
>   sting rays."
>
> The shark whale swam from one corner of the '**glass/section**' to the
>   other.
>
> There was a jellyfish in the middle of the **glass**. (OK, this one sounds weird).

I'm not very sure which is the best word to use here.

**EDIT:**

For example, this would be a 'section':

[image]

Is it right to say, for instance:

> The people are looking through the **glass**.

or

> There are many people in this **section**.

(I just need a general term that people would immediately understand. I need this for a novel I'm writing.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Both of your examples at the end are fine, but I think the word you might be looking for is **tank**, which fits perfectly in all three of your constructions at the beginning of your question.

If you want to be consistent, (though you don't need to be in this case), you'd need to reform your later sentences to

> The people are looking into the **tank**.

and

> There are many people at this **tank**.

Comment: Damn! I think that is the word I was looking for. But I'm curious about the other answers.

Answer (score 5):

What about "exhibit"? Or are you talking about different **sections** of the same **tank**?

Comment: That's the first word that came to my mind, but I ruled it out. "Exhibit" usually refers to something larger. e.g. The shark exhibit might have several tanks.

Answer (score 3):

I do believe that **tank** is a great answer, **water tank** to be more precise (there are gas tanks too). The glass you are looking through is called glass window (don't have idea why). But when you go to see different species of marine life you go to place with different [maricultures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mariculture).

Answer (score 2):

I don't recall aquariums using the word "tank" or "water tank". I believe the word of choice is "habitat".